# Angular - Get days Of Week for weather info

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to get days of the week from data weather Json , I am using this code 
'

```
 var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var date = new Date();
$scope.wDay = dayNames[date.getDay()];
```

html

```
{{wDay}}
```

get result only one day 'sun' not all days of week

full json data

```
 {

  "daily": {
    "summary": "لا أمطار خلال الأسبوع مع درجات حرارة ترتفع حتى 50°C يوم الأربعاء",
    "icon": "clear-day",
    "data": [
      {
        "time": 1469912400,
        "summary": "اجواء جافة خلال اليوم",
        "icon": "clear-day",
        "sunriseTime": 1469931375,
        "sunsetTime": 1469981058,
        "moonPhase": 0.91,
        "precipIntensity": 0,
        "precipIntensityMax": 0,
        "precipProbability": 0,
        "temperatureMin": 30.7,
        "temperatureMinTime": 1469930400,

      },
```

Comment: date.getDay() always return today Day.

Answer (score 0):

This program is time dependent.

```
new Date().getDay()
```

wil always retuen you 0 today

Answer (score 0):

You will only see Sunday - as it's what you specifically test for it with:
`dayNames[date.getDay()];` - number corresponding to the day of the week for the given date.

If you want them all, simply ng-repeat `dayNames`:

```
  var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  var date = new Date();

  function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.today = dayNames[date.getDay()];
      $scope.all = dayNames;
  }

  Today is {{today}}!

  <div ng-repeat="day in all">
    {{day}}
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7751/

*Edit*:
change in the scope of the question, so here's an addition to the answer. It can of course be written in a more condensed manner, but expanded for brevity:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7896/

I added MomentJS (http://momentjs.com)  - great for working with dates.

```
//Added a filter to grab today's data from JSON
myApp.filter('GetToday',function(){
  return function(epoch) {

    //Get today
    var today = moment();

    //Loop through all the daily nodes from the JSON
    for (var i = 0; i < epoch.length; i++) {

        //convert UNIX timestamp to date
        var json = moment.unix(epoch[i].time); 

        //determine difference between dates
        var duration = moment.duration(json.diff(today));

        //convert the difference into hours
        var hours = duration.asHours();

        //if it's more than 0 and less than 24 (today) return this node
        if(hours > 0 && hours < 24) {
            return epoch[i];
        }
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){
        $scope.daily = $filter('GetToday')(data[0].daily.data);
}]);
```

Comment: you dont understand me , i want get days of week in weather data json , via code daysnames

Comment: I answered based on your question and the example provided. Can you post the full JSON object you are using for your weather data?

Comment: Then, please clarify your question. Also - I requested you post your full JSON object.

Comment: @razak - it's not the full object. And can you please clarify the question? What you asked was answered?

Comment: thanks for Interest , i want get time form weather data json , using . time in data json is Timestamp this full data json  https://api.forecast.io/forecast/3a6d5408bc15a469385cf59ee96c0205/33.2314641,44.332978?lang=ar&units=ca&callback=angular.callbacks._0

Comment: I don't mind assisting, but this is completely different from your initial question. To clarify you want to get the weather conditions from the JSON based on the current timestamp?

Comment: exactly ,  timestamp in daily section of data json